# FindOption vs QueryBuilder in TypeORM

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Is there any limitation with FindOption in [typeorm](https://typeorm.github.io/index.html)?

Something that we can do with QueryBuilder but not with FindOption?

Because I'm trying to create a genericRepository and for my select queries It's good if I can send FindOption object from every where that I call my genericRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some special methods in query builder which you can use, but you would rarely use them. In most of case FindOption is enough for your queries, but I recommend to use QueryBuilder, because using it you will write more complex and readable queries more easily.